# .load jquery send double values

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

When I try to load the first .load it passes 1 variable without any problem, I receive this variable from a _GET method to store it in a data-id button attribute to pass it back to another .load, in this second file I receive the variable again in a _GET method and the code does its thing, but when doing the process again from the beginning, in the second .load the variable is duplicated and the alert() script shows 2 times, as well as the process of this same file too.

I have tried with .empty() and .remove() functions, likewise I have tried to load from the last .load the first file that filters the main file, but the problem still occurs.

**(The main to send variable to first file in .load)**

```
                    <p>Select a category</p>
                    <select name="category" id="category" class="form-control" required>
                        <option disabled selected value>category</option>
                        <option value="1">all cat</option>
                    </select>
    <div id="table-category" name="table-category"></div>
```

```
$("#consult").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    idCategory = $('#category').val();
    $('#table-category').load('../public/tabla-proyectos.php?v1='+idCategory );
});
```

**The second .load in that id="table-category"**

```
    $category = $_GET['v1'];
        <script>
          alert(<?php echo $category;?>); <!-- In this part dont have problems with the variable because return only one result -->
          </script>
<button id="admin" name="admin" data-id="<?php echo $category;?>">Show</button>
<div id="map"></div>

<script>

$(document).on("click", "#admin", function () { <!-- I think there's the problem -->
    category = $(this).data('id');
    $('#map').load('../public/mapa.php?val1='+category);
    });
</script>
```

**Final .load file**

```
$categoy_id = $_GET['val1'];

<script>
alert(<?php echo $category_id;?>); <!-- The first time OK, but trying again from the beginning repeat the process 2 times -->
</script>
```

Comment: Makes sense. With each load you're binding a new event to document. That code only needs to run once, and can run before any click happens.

Comment: @KevinB at your comment, in _With each load you're binding a new event to document_ ,if I try to put inside the last file a script $('map').empty(); and likewise a $('table-category').empty(); would remove everything inside this div in the file, this would give me the "opportunity" to start over without having to reload the page, but this don't work.

Comment: No matter where you move it, it's binding to the document which doesn't go away or get unbound until the page reloads. that means... you can move it to right above or below your original click event binding. It only needs to run once.

Comment: @KevinB I post my answer to this post, Taking into account your answer when simplifying the main file, in this case it is necessary to have several files since I am working with large amounts of data and the first instance is a filter so as not to saturate the information page in the second file that I do in the .load, that's why it's impossible for me to try to load it all at once (later it's easier for me to place everything inside a frame)thanks for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it in the following way:

I have taken the script of the second file and I have put it in the main file, adding to it an .empty() function so that it cleans all its values ​​before returning to show a new result inside this div, I have also added a new script inside the last .load file being the following:

**Main file now see like:**

```
    $("#consult").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        idCategory = $('#category').val();
        $('#table-category').load('../public/tabla-proyectos.php?v1='+idCategory );
    });

$(document).on("click", "#admin", function () {
    $('#map').empty();
    category = $(this).data('id');
    $('#map').load('../public/mapa.php?val1='+category);
});
```

**The second file .load don't have script because now is on the main**

**The last file script now see like:**

```
    idCategory = $('#category').val();
     $('#table-category').empty();
            $('#table-category').load('../public/tabla-proyectos.php? 
   v1='+idCategory );
```